# boost.thread dead-lock and self-deletion

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I am using `boost::thread_group` to create(using 
`thread_group::create_thread()`) and dispatch threads. In order to limit 
the max thread numbers,  at the end of each thread, I remove the thread 
from the `thread_group` and delete the thread itself(so that I could 
decide whether new threads need to be created). However it hangs 
somewhere between the creation and deletion of the last thread (say the 
999th one of 999 in total).

My questions are:

- is it OK to delete the thread from
  within itself like what I do? if 
  not, what the best way to achieve
  this
- why does my code hangs?

Below are the related code:

//1- code to create and dispatch thread

```
 { 
        //mutex for map<thread_id, thread*> operations 
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(m_mutex_for_ptr); 

        // create a thread for this->f(duplicate_hashes) 
        boost::thread* p = m_thread_group.create_thread(boost::bind( 
            &detectiveT<equal_predicate>::f, 
            this, 
            duplicate_hashes 
            )); 

        // save the <thread_id,thread pointer> map for later lookup & deletion 
        m_thread_ptrs.insert(make_pair(p->get_id(), p)); 

        // log to console for debug 
        cout << "thread created: " 
            << p->get_id() << ", " 
            << m_thread_group.size() << ", " m_thread_ptrs.size() << 
"\n";     
    }
```

//2- code of the thread execution

```
void f(list<map_iterator_type>& l) 
{ 
    Do_something(l);    
    boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit(boost::bind( 
        &detectiveT<equal_predicate>::remove_this_thread, 
        this 
        ));                     
}
```

//3- code to delete the thread itself

```
void remove_this_thread() 
{ 

    { 
        //mutex for map<thread_id, thread*> operations 
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(m_mutex_for_ptr);                   
        boost::thread::id this_id(boost::this_thread::get_id()); 

        map<boost::thread::id, boost::thread*>::iterator itr; 

        itr = (m_thread_ptrs.find(this_id)); 

        if(m_thread_ptrs.end() != itr) 
        { 
            // remove it from the control of thread_group 
            m_thread_group.remove_thread(itr->second); 
            // delete it 
            delete itr->second; 

            // remove from the map 
            m_thread_ptrs.erase(this_id); 

            // log to console for debug 
            cout << "thread erased: " 
                << this_id << ", " 
                << m_thread_group.size() << ", " 
                << m_thread_ptrs.size() << "\n";             
        } 
    }               
}
```

Comment: If you run the program in the debugger, what is happening in the various threads when it hangs?

Comment: from procexp.exe, I can see all threads are in "Wait:UserRequest" state. I suspect some recursive locks happens between the thread_group internal lock and the outer lock I introduce(i.e. lk(m_mutex_for_ptr)), but not sure how. I was once lucky by commentting out this line "  << m_thread_group.size() << ", " " in void remove_this_thread(), but could not reproduce that...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Just call `detach()` on the thread and delete its object. This will make a thread release its resources automatically upon exit (see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).  Otherwise it will either deadlock joining itself or become a zombie because nobody will join it when it exits.

Comment: @Vlad: No need to `detach()` if you delete the object. And I believe there are a whole bunch of potential deadlocks around (a) making the address of the object visible to the thread code (b) threads removing themselves when you also support `join_all()` operations from the main thread (which you must). Also, no OS was specified, so pthread-only guarantees are not sufficient.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, right, just because OS was not specified, using abstract wacky wrappers becomes walking in the dark. "Deatch" supposed to detach the thread, make "join()" unnecessary and prevent from `thread` class from calling join from destructor, or whatever group wrapper is used. I guess you just have to check what the heck that implementation is doing.

Comment: @Vlad: It doesn't make "join()" unnecessary whatsoever. You don't want to just "detach and forget" a thread if you're shutting down an enclosing object and your thread uses shared data. You need to know that it's [interrupted and ] finished before you proceed to clean up that shared data, otherwise you mangle your memory.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That is a main point of detachable threads. If that doesn't work for you, you have to create your own "thread manager" of some sort. Because threads cannot join themselves. One of the possible solutions that comes to mind is to create a "master thread" that is solely responsible for joining other threads, and can be shut down by the main thread. It has to provide other threads with event-queue mechanism so that other threads, when need to self-terminate, enqueue the message to "master" and exit. Then "master" thread shall wake up and cleanup their resource by joining.

Comment: @Vlad: And that's exactly what this question is about, isn't it? FWIW: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/have-i-thought-of-everything-in-this-wrapper-around-boostthread-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try to recycle the threads, since creation/destruction is expensive?

Code a thread pool class and send tasks to it. The pool will either queue the tasks if it has no more available threads, create threads if current_threads < max_threads or just use what thread is available.

Suggested implementation:

Find out what your ideal thread count is. This is usually equal to the number of processors.
Depending on how complicated you want this to be, you could create all the threads in the pool at once or add threads if current-thread-count < ideal-thread-count and all the existing threads are busy executing tasks.

Assuming that you are creating all your threads at once, you need to pass a worker function to each of the threads to execute. This worker function will wait for tasks to become available and then execute them. Because the function either executes a task or waits for it, it won't return and *the thread won't be destroyed*.

The thread pool can keep track of a task queue and manage a wait condition that indicates when there are tasks available in the queue. Each thread worker function waits on the wait condition and when there's a task available it wakes up and tries to do the task. 
You will have to do some synchronization; the easiest way would be to try and find an available thread pool implementation, like the one in Windows (Vista+ I think) or the one in QtConcurrent which would allow you to just pass the task, call run and let the OS/library worry about everything.

Later edit:

Check out http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to recycle a thread? My experience is that the execution of a thread is passed with the ctor, and there's no way to change it and re-use this very thread object again.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me, I've found Boost.Task and will try how much I can leverage with it.

Comment: Although you did not answer my question directly, you suggested a better way to have invalid my problems. So I accepted your reply as the answer. Thanks.